# Semi-transparent background for Google presentation text box

Tags: google-slides

Is it possible to set the background of a text box in Google presentation to be semi-transparent? All I see are options to either transparent (a.k.a. "no fill") or completely opaque text boxes.

Answer (score 55):

Yup, you can set the background color to be semi-transparent. Use the custom color option, it gives you the ability to set transparency.

[image: Setting Opacity on box in Google Docs Presentation]

The result will be..

[image: Transparent example on Google Docs]

Comment: Kudos Deepak! I never knew this existed. Deleting my other answer now.

Comment: Yup, it exists but not easily visible. Hope the OP sees my answer now :D

Comment: @DeepakKamat I guess it was a *partially* visible  (semi transparent) feature? :-)

Comment: This custom color technique also works for creating semi-transparent shapes in Google Slides.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to Deepak's answer:

If after following [Deepak's instructions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/39687/17424), the text area rectangle has a transparent background, but the area immediately behind the text characters themselves still has a solid white (or other solid color) background, then:

[image: Google Presentation Transparent Text]

1. Select the text box.
2. From the Format menu, select Text Color.
3. Select "Highlight".
4. Click "Transparent".

Answer (score 0):

You can also format it's drop shadow so that the variables are transparency 0, angle 90, distance 3-5, and blur radius 3-5.